# Magento2: variables

Tags: magento2, checkout, variables

I need to configure a script that sends a survey to clients to fill in for trusted reviews.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    client_email = ‘here I want display: CUSTOMER EMAIL ADDRESS’;
    order_id = ‘here I want display: ORDER ID’;
    shop_product_ids =‘here I want display: PRODUCT ID’;
</script>
```

I must put the script in the successful.phtml checkout in the `<body>` section.

Can anyone help what variables should be here to get this customer data?

Customer email address:

```
client_email = ‘here I want display: CUSTOMER EMAIL ADDRESS’;
```

Order ID:

```
order_id = ‘here I want display: ORDER ID’;
```

Product ID:

```
shop_product_ids =‘here I want display: PRODUCT ID’;
```

Comment: Do you want to add this script on **Success.phtml** file?

Comment: Abhishek, yes I want add this script to success.phtml

Answer (score 1):

you can get customer data as

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($block- >getOrderId()); // pass orderId

if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
  $firstname      = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
  $lastname       = $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
  $customer_name  = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
  $telephone_tmp  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
  $customer_email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
  $postal         = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
  $city           = $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
  $address_tmp    = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
  echo $customer_name."<-------- new customer";
}
 /* getting Register Account Details */
else {
   $customer  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
  //else, they're a normal registered user.
  $firstname = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
  $lastname  = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
  echo $customer_name = $firstname.' '.$lastname ."<--------   exist customer";
}
```

Order id as

```
$block->getOrderId();
```

and products items as

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId();
$cartData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository')->get($quoteId)->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Comment: Arslan, I no want full data customer. Please check my topic. I only want in this fields display: client_email = ‘here I want display:  CUSTOMER EMAIL ADDRESS’; order_id = ‘here I want display: ORDER ID’; shop_product_ids =‘here I want display: PRODUCT ID’;

Comment: You can get customer email in a variable like this
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($block- >getOrderId()); // pass orderId

if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
  $customer_email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
}

here $customer_email variable has customer email address

Comment: Ok sure... ....